# String split method creates a first element "", how to avoid it?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I read from a properties file a parameter like this {TA;TD;TE;TG;TI;TN;TNG;TP;TR;TS;TT}, and I need to split it to remove {} and ;. For that I use:

`String[] zzz = myString.split("[{;}]");`

The problems comes when sending that string to a method that must add it to database (it doesn't matter how), and then realize that there's a first element that is empty. That means, when I print it, I see:

blank space

TA

TD

TE

...etc

If I debug it, I see that the elements being extracted from the initial string are: **""**, "TA", "TD", "TE", etc.

And because of this **""** (the method where the string is sent automatically inserts comma between elements) my row in database is like that:

,TA,TD,TE... etc

How can I avoid that? I've tried also to split it with the limiter parameter, but it doesn't work either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `myString.replaceFirst("^[{;}]","").split("[{;}]");`

Comment: or, in your special case, `myString.substring(1).split("[;}]");`

Comment: or `myString.replaceAll("[{}]","").split(";");`

Comment: @RafaQuiñonero surely that sill leaves you with an empty element at the end of the list as well...

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik My poor knowledge of Java shows through: just looked it up and you are correct, trailing empty elements are discarded unless you specify a negative limit.

Comment: myString.substring(1).split("[;}]"); that worked prefectly and it's the most simple answer, if you put it as an answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use make this simple change to your code:

```
 myString.substring(1).split("[;}]");
```

This just skips over the first char, which is an open brace. The regex can be slightly simpler, too, since you don't have to split on the open brace anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just strip the `{}` characters from the start and the end?

```
myString.substring(1, myString.length() - 1).split(";");
```

Comment: I need the {} to separate this elements from other ones, it's a bit complicated.

Comment: I need the brackets because I'm splitting before split that parameter with commas, and then I need a second splitter to split those parameters, but at the first read it's as one parameter, that's why I need the {}, or [], or any other symbol to contain them grouped.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the negated pattern you provided and use a `Matcher` to get the elements:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "{TA;TD;TE;TG;TI;TN;TNG;TP;TR;TS;TT}";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[{;]([^{;}]*)").matcher(data);

    while (m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Outputs:

```
TA
TD
TE
TG
TI
TN
TNG
TP
TR
TS
TT
```

Comment: `"[{;]([^{;}]*)"` and `m.group(1)` would allow for empty elements in the middle: `{TA;;TE}`.